# How to include an already documented method in jsdoc-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, closures, jsdoc

I have a JavaScript singleton object created with closure method:

```
/**
 * This is the singleton.
 *
 * @namespace window.Something.Singleton
 */
window.Something.Singleton = (function() {
  /**
   * Foo method.
   *
   * @return {String} this method always returns with <code>bar</code>
   */
  function _foo() { return "bar"; }

  /**
   * @lends window.Something.Singleton#
   */
  return {
    /**
     * @borrows window.Something-_foo
     * @function
     */
    foo: _foo
  };
}());
```

But the [jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) does not generate the inherited documentation from `_foo` method to the `foo` method what I would like to have.

If I write `@see` instead of `@borrows` it works (inserts a link to the correct method), but I don't want to copy&paste the documentation for the `foo` method to have a public documentation as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some tests, and I have good news and bad news :). The good news is that it looks like you can get this to work by putting the `@borrows` tag in the Singleton doc comment:

```
/**
 * This is the singleton.
 *
 * @namespace Something.Singleton
 * @borrows Something.Singleton-_foo as foo
 */
Something.Singleton = (function() {
   // etc
})());
```

But this has several ramifications, good and bad:

- The `foo` function is marked `static`. This is probably a good thing, as it seems to be accurate as I understand your code.
- With the code as it is currently shown (i.e. no more methods on the singleton, etc), you can dispense with the `@lends` tag entirely, unless you want to include it for clarity. If all methods are listed as `@borrows` on the top singleton namespace, then you don't need to further document them in the returned object. Again, this is probably a good thing.
- The bad news is that I couldn't get this to work unless the borrowed method was explicitly marked `@public` - which makes it show up, redundantly, in the documentation. I think this is unavoidable - if jsdoc-toolkit thinks the method is private, it won't create documentation, so you can't refer to it (I get `WARNING: Can't borrow undocumented Something.Singleton-_foo.`). If the method is public, it gets displayed in the documentation.

So this works:

```
/**
 * This is the singleton.
 *
 * @namespace Something.Singleton
 * @borrows Something.Singleton-_foo as foo
 */
Something.Singleton = (function() {
  /**
   * @public
   * Foo method.
   *
   * @return {String} this method always returns with <code>bar</code>
   */
  function _foo() { return "bar"; }

  return {
    foo: _foo
  };
}());
```

...in that it copies the documentation for `_foo` to `foo`, but it will display `_foo` in the documentation page as well:

```
Method Summary
<inner>  _foo()
<static>  Something.Singleton.foo()
```

Probably the best workaround is simply to forget `@borrows` entirely and explicitly name `_foo` as `Something.Singleton.foo` in the doc comment, marking it as a public function (you could dispense with `@public` if you didn't name your inner function with an underscore, but this tells jsdoc-toolkit to treat it as private unless told otherwise):

```
/**
 * This is the singleton.
 *
 * @namespace Something.Singleton
 */
Something.Singleton = (function() {
  /**
   * @name Something.Singleton#foo
   * @public
   * @function
   * Foo method.
   *
   * @return {String} this method always returns with <code>bar</code>
   */
  function _foo() { return "bar"; }

  return {
    foo: _foo
  };
}());
```

This will produce the code documentation you're looking for, and puts the comment next to the actual code it relates to. It doesn't fully satisfy one's need to have the computer do all the work - you have to be very explicit in the comment - but I think it's just as clear, if not more so, than what you had originally, and I don't think it's much more maintenance (even in your original example, you'd have to change all your doc comments if you renamed `Something.Singleton`).

Comment: The last example fits perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: It would be even better to avoid to make it static btw.

Comment: Okay, I found it out `@name Something.Singleton#methodName` is the solution.

Comment: I adjusted my code accordingly - I wasn't sure if you wanted it to be considered static or not. Glad this worked for you!

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagBorrows

`@borrows otherMemberName as thisMemberName`
`otherMemberName` - Required: the namepath to the other member.
`thisMemberName` - Required: the new name that the member is being assigned to in this class.

```
/** @constructor */
function Remote() {
}

/** Connect to a remote address. */
Remote.prototype.transfer = function(address, data) {
}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @borrows Remote#transfer as this.send
 */
function SpecialWriter() {
    this.send = Remote.prototype.transfer;
}
```

Any documentation for Remote#transfer will also appear as documentation for SpecialWriter#send.